# SQL condition: (A=B AND C LIKE %D%) OR (A LIKE %B% AND C=D)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, conditional-statements

I've got a table of first names and last names.

I'm trying to make a jQuery instant search on an input, in order to find very quickly and precisely a person in a huge list of people.

When the first word is entered in the input, it might be the first name or the last name.

I do this : `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE firstName LIKE %content% OR lastName LIKE %content%`

When two words are entered, it might be:
* the full firstname and a bit of the lastname
* the full lastname and a bit of the firstame

So I tried this query : `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (firstName = content1 AND lastName LIKE %content2%) OR ( lastName = content1 AND firstName LIKE %content2%)`

Unfortunately parenthesis seems to do nothing, and the query is not interpreted this way, I've got a lot of results, basically produced by the two LIKE %% condition

Anyone had deal with this before and could give me a hand?

Thanx

Comment: just to clarify -- in your second query, content and %content% are actually representing different strings, right?  So, you're not doing firstName = 'John Sm' AND lastName LIKE '%John Sm%', but rather firstname = 'John' AND lastName LIKE '%Sm%'?

Comment: do you mean `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (firstName = content1 AND lastName LIKE %content2%) OR ( lastName = content2 AND firstName LIKE %content1%)`?

Comment: yep my mistake. right above. I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the words is going to be the full first name of the full last name, while the other word is a partial of the other, why don't you split up the words first? Then you'd pass in two paramaters and have:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    (
        firstName = %content1%
        AND lastName LIKE %content2%
    ) OR (
        lastName = %content1%
        AND firstName LIKE %content2%
    )
```

Comment: That's nearly the answer. It's more LIKE content2% no?

Comment: @CoBaLt2760: you're right--looks like I had a formatting issue; I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to need to split the two words entered and use them indepenently in your query.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably work this way (assuming that the two words are in the content variable):

```
SELECT ... WHERE
   CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastName) LIKE content%
   OR CONCAT(lastName, " ", firstName) LIKE content%
```

however this approach would not be very efficient (no index usage). I would split the two words into two variables (word1, word2) and make it something like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE
    (firstName = word1 AND lastName LIKE word2%)
    OR (lastName = word1 AND firstName LIKE word2%)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer you were right with content% and not %content%

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 
    (firstName = 'content1' AND lastName LIKE content2%) 
OR 
    (lastName = 'content1' AND firstName LIKE content2%)
```

Answer (score 0):

> When two words are entered, it might
>   be: * the full firstname and a bit of
>   the lastname * the full lastname and a
>   bit of the firstame

If it is ALL of (exact match) the first or last name, then the = test seems correct.  Just in case it is an error in the PHP part, this is how it should look like.

```
$qry = '
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE (firstName = content1 AND lastName LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(content2)."%')
   OR ( lastName = content1 AND firstName LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(content2)."%')';
```

If it is a bit of both, then you need the wildcard twice

```
$qry = '
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE (firstName LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(content1)."%' AND lastName LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(content2)."%')
   OR ( lastName LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(content1)."%' AND firstName LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(content2)."%')';
```